# Adding Custom Autotext for MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to know how to add a custom, dynamic Autotext entry for Microsoft Word.  I want to be able to Insert>Autotext>Header/Footer>"Last Friday" and have last Friday's date show up in the spot and keep it updated like inserting the Date Autotext updates each time the document is opened.

I have the VB code necessary to compute last Friday's date and return it as a String, but I am having trouble finding how to tie the function's output to a new Autotext entry.

It would also be acceptable to add a custom entry into the Insert>Field list as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is another thread here

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.beginners/2007-02/msg00050.html

This might have a solution for you.